# Send data in Angular to backend Django for sending email

Tags: django, angular, api

I have contact form in Angular which use httpclient for Post method to django which is sending email with all data information from Angular to my email adress. In PostMan everythink work fine. What is mean "10" and "14" after response 200?

I got in console:

```
Dave dave@gmail.com hi how are you?.
[25/Oct/2020 12:10:47] "POST /send_email/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10
```

but when I try in my angular I got:

```
None None None
[25/Oct/2020 12:14:11] "POST /send_email/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14
```

So if PostMan works fine, the problem is somewhere in Angular, but I don't know what is wrong.

django def in views:

```
 @csrf_exempt
    def send_email(request):
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        print(name, email, message)
        try:
            send_mail(f'{name} wysłał wiadomość z Zakuro',
                      f'adres: {email}/// wiadomość: {message}',
                      'email@gmail.com',
                      ['secondemail@gmail.com'],
                      fail_silently=False)
            send_mail('Thanks for contact with Zakuro',
                      'Hi. I will response as soon as possible.',
                      'email@gmail.com',
                      [f'{email}'],
                      fail_silently=False)
            return HttpResponse('email sent')
        except:
            return HttpResponse('email not sent')
```

django url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('send_email/', send_email),
]
```

angular component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-contact',
      templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./contact.component.sass']
    })
    export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(
        private cookieService: CookieService,
        private router: Router,
        private apiService: ApiService
      ){}
  name = "";
  email = "";
  message = "";
    sendButton(){
        this.wrongEmail = false
        this.wrongName = false
        this.wrongMessage = false
        var pattern = /^[^ ]+@[^]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/
        if (this.email.match(pattern)) {
          if(this.name.length > 1){
            if(this.message.length > 10){
              this.apiService.sendEmail(this.name, this.email, this.message).subscribe(
                result => {
                  this.isSent = true;
                  this.name = "";
                  this.email = "";
                  this.message = "";
                },
                error => console.log("contact error")
              )
            }
            else this.wrongMessage=true
          }
          else this.wrongName=true
        }
        else this.wrongEmail=true
      }
```

my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private cookieService: CookieService,
  ) { }
  headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  });
  
  loginUrl = "https://zakuro-warehouse.herokuapp.com/login/"
  listUrl = "https://zakuro-warehouse.herokuapp.com/api/login-history/"
  mailUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/send_email/"
 
  sendEmail(name: string, email: string, message: string){
    const mail = JSON.stringify({name, email, message})
    return this.httpClient.post(this.mailUrl, mail)
  }
```

HTML

```html
<div [hidden]="isSent">
    <div class="contact contactGrid">
        <input
            class="half"
            [ngClass]="{redBorder: wrongEmail}"
            type="email"
            placeholder="your email"
            [(ngModel)]="email"
        />
        <input
            class="half"
            [ngClass]="{redBorder: wrongName}"
            type="text"
            placeholder="your name"
            [(ngModel)]="name"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <textarea
            rows="6"
            [ngClass]="{redBorder: wrongMessage}"
            class="full"
            placeholder="your message"
            [(ngModel)]="message"
        ></textarea>
        <button (click)="sendButton()">Send</button>
        <span [ngClass]="{showSpan: wrongEmail}"
            >Write email address first</span
        >
        <span [ngClass]="{showSpan: wrongName}">Write your name</span>
        <span [ngClass]="{showSpan: wrongMessage}"
            >You forgot wrote message</span
        >
    </div>
</div>
<div [hidden]="!isSent">
    <h2>Your message sent successfully.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see `None None None` as well. Can you check that value as well.

Comment: Shashank. What you mean?

Comment: @DamianZakuro Can you post the template file as well

Comment: @B45i I added HTML to my first post , but I also checked this in console and everything fine.

Comment: @DamianZakuro Open the network tab in developer tools and check if the request actually has the data

Comment: @B45i network tab give me: {name: "testName", email: "test123@gmail.com", message: "testMessage string"}
email: "test123@gmail.com"
message: "testMessage string"
name: "testName"

Comment: but i also got response from except in Django: email not sent